# can't Deserialize a list of different types of children objects

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json packet consisting of a dacket header(under PACKET_HEADER) + a number of different types of messages(under DATA). These messages have a same parent class:

```
//my packet class
public class Packet {
    public PacketHeader PACKET_HEADER;
    public Message[] DATA;
}

//my parent message class:
public class Message {

    public enum MessageType {
        WHOAREYOU,
        TimeData,
        Ready,
        LocationData
    }

    public MessageType getMessageType() {
        return MESSAGE_TYPE;
    }

    public void setMessageType(MessageType MessageType) {
        this.MESSAGE_TYPE = MessageType;
    }

    private MessageType MESSAGE_TYPE;
    //declaring public for simplicity
    public String SENDER;
    public String SENDER_TYPE;

}

//sample child class:
public class TimeMessage extends Message {

    private int tick;
    public int getTick()
    {
        return tick;
    }
```

and I deserialize input like this:

```
 @Override
    public Handler create(Connector connector, Object packet, int clientID) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Packet pack = gson.fromJson(packet.toString(), Packet.class);
        System.out.println("Number of messages : " + pack.PACKET_HEADER.NOF_MESSAGES );//ok
        for(Message msg : pack.DATA)
        {
            switch (msg.getMessageType()) {
                //enters the switch successfully
                case TimeData: {               
                    System.out.println("Sender:  " + msg.SENDER  + "  Sender_type: " + msg.SENDER_TYPE);//ok
                    TimeMessage time_msg = (TimeMessage) msg;//NOT ok, generates exception!!!!
                    //...
                    return new TimeHandler(time_msg, connector, clientID);
                }
                default:                    
                    System.out.println("Switch " + msg.getMessageType() + " is invalid");
                    return null;
            }
        }
       return null; 

    }
```

Do you have any idea why I cant cast to a child class? how do i solve it. Thank a lot in advance.

Comment: What's the concrete exception you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Gson cannot handle **polymorphism** without a little help.

Indeed **JSON does not keep the type information** so when Gson will deserialize the document it will create **only Message instances**, not instance of subclasses like *TimeMessage*, because it has no way of guessing the correct type.

You have to use an additional component, the ***RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory***.

I've just written an article about it on my blog: http://pragmateek.com/javajson-mapping-with-gson

And here is the section you're interested in: http://pragmateek.com/javajson-mapping-with-gson/#Preserving_type_information

Please ask if you still have the issue.

EDIT:

here is a full sample for your specific situation:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.typeadapters.RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory;

public class Program
{
    public static class Packet
    {
        public Message[] DATA;
    }

    public static enum MessageType
    {
        WHOAREYOU,
        TimeData,
        Ready,
        LocationData
    }

    //my parent message class:
    public static class Message {

        public MessageType getMessageType() {
            return MESSAGE_TYPE;
        }

        public void setMessageType(MessageType MessageType) {
            this.MESSAGE_TYPE = MessageType;
        }

        private MessageType MESSAGE_TYPE;
        //declaring public for simplicity
        public String SENDER;
        public String SENDER_TYPE;

    }

    //sample child class:
    public static class TimeMessage extends Message
    {
        private int tick;
        public int getTick()
        {
            return tick;
        }
        public TimeMessage(int tick)
        {
            this.tick = tick;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Message[] messages = { new TimeMessage(123) };

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(Message.class, "$type").registerSubtype(TimeMessage.class));
        Gson gson = builder.create();

        String json = gson.toJson(messages);

        Message[] outMessages = gson.fromJson(json, Message[].class);
        TimeMessage tm = (TimeMessage)outMessages[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please repost the relevant sections from your blog here so that in case your blog goes down,  your answer is still useful in the future?

Comment: This type of downcasting from parent to child is OK ? People don't usually like downcasting in the code. Is there any other option ?

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo: I guess you're talking about `TimeMessage tm = (TimeMessage)outMessages[0]`? Sometimes you have no choice: if you are lucky you only need the `Message` functional contract and can leverage polymorphism, but if you need to access specific data you need to downcast to a more specialized implementation. Even if it's not the ideal situation this is not an issue by itself. So to answer your questions: downcasting is OK as long as you know what you're doing; and here, AFAIK, there is no other option.

Comment: Yeah I have a weird design I'm facing which has similar problem. I get a Json Array of with mix of Child classes and I have to return a List back to client. Currently I'm returning properly created List of BaseClass using type field in json. And client has to first check the type field and then cast to proper child class. I'm not sure if this is the only option I have.

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo: always hard to give a definitive answer without code but seems like you've done all you can. Check this: what kind of objects does the user give you if any, e.g. to persist them in a JSON file? If it's a `List<BaseClass>` then the user can't expect that your API return anything more specific, it's the very principle of polymorphism: you **abstract** the true nature of entities, hidden behind a **functional contract**.

Comment: @Pragmateek I already added a question with proper code yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438546/parse-json-with-mixed-child-objects-via-gson-and-send-back-as-list

me and my team decided that it's actually kind of broken(not well designed) web-service which gives mixed classes in same bucket. We might go for fix webservice route and then do additional changes on client api.

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo: I've added a comment on the other question, so that you can have the best of both worlds: polymorphism by default, and separated collections if the client wants.