# Parse json with mixed child objects via gson and send back as list

Tags: java, json, oop, design-patterns, gson

I'm facing a problem related to parsing json which have mixed arrays of child classes, and I need to provide that as java list back to client.

**Sample JSON:**

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [
    {
      "type": "one",
       "Id": "2170676",
       "count": "456",
       "title": "title",
       "description": "description",
       "oneMemberOne": "11",
       "oneMemberTwo": "12",
    }
    {
      "type": "two",
      "Id": "2170677",
      "count": "123",
      "title": "title",
      "description": "description",
      "twoMemberOne": "21",
      "twoMemberTwo": "22",
    }
  ]
}
```

**I created one Parent class and two child class from this:**

> **Num** : type, Id, count, title, description fields
>
> **One extends Num** : oneMemberOne, oneMemberTwo
>
> **Two extends Num** : twoMemberOne, twoMemberTwo

Now my question:
I have a method for asking results. Say it `List<Num> getResults()`

- I parse the data properly like this:

  ```
  List<Num> result = new ArrayList<Num>();
  JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
  JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(lastResponsePayload).getAsJsonObject()
  JsonArray results = jsonObject.get("results").getAsJsonArray();
  for (JsonElement element : results) {
       JsonObject trs = element.getAsJsonObject();
       String type = trs.get("type").getAsString();

       if (type.equals("one") {
            One one = new Gson().fromJson(element, One.class);
            result.add(product);
       } else if (type.equals("two") {
            Two two = new Gson().fromJson(element, Two.class);
            result.add(metaproduct);
       }
  return result;
  ```
- Now, on client side, after I get the list, i have to do this:

  ```
  List<Num> results = getResults();
  List<One> oness = new ArrayList<One>();
  List<Two> twoss = new ArrayList<Two>();
  for(Num n : results) {
       if(n.type.equals("one")
            oness.add((One) n);
       else
            twoss.add((Two) n);
  ```

**Is this a good design for this scenario ?**

**User of this API has to downcast everytime based on the type field of parent class. Because webservice gives me mixed array of child classes, I have to do this. Is there any better approach to this problem ?**

- One another approach in my mind is to create a `Result` class which contains two members `One` and `Two` and provide my a `List<Result>` instead of `List<Num>`, 
  but then user has to check whether member is `null` or not and then take appropriate steps.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest that you have another class something like this. It prevents client code from spinning through list again and parsing out records. Please note I have not run this code to test it.

```
public class Result {
    private List<One> oness;
    private List<Two> twoss;

    public List<One> getOness() {
        return oness;
    }

    public void setOness(List<One> oness) {
        this.oness = oness;
    }

    public List<Two> getTwoss() {
        return twoss;
    }

    public void setTwoss(List<Two> twoss) {
        this.twoss = twoss;
    }
}
```

And change

`List<Num> getResults()`

To

`Result getResults()`

also user will not have to check for nulls if you modify your parsing logic. Please see that in case we don't have results we are not returning null list but EmptyList.

```
Result result = new Result();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(lastResponsePayload).getAsJsonObject()
    JsonArray results = jsonObject.get("results").getAsJsonArray();

    List<One> oness = null;
    List<Two> twoss = null;

    for (JsonElement element : results) {
         JsonObject trs = element.getAsJsonObject();
         String type = trs.get("type").getAsString();

         if (type.equals("one")) {
             if(oness == null) {
                 oness = new ArrayList<One>();
                 result.setOness(oness);
             }
             One one = new Gson().fromJson(element, One.class);
             oness.add(product);
         } else if (type.equals("two")) {
             if(twoss == null) {
                 twoss = new ArrayList<Two>();
                 result.setTwoss(twoss);
             }
              Two two = new Gson().fromJson(element, Two.class);
              twoss.add(metaproduct);
         }
         if(oness == null) {
             result.setOness(Collections.<One>EMPTY_LIST);
         }
         if(twoss == null) {
             result.setTwoss(Collections.<Two>EMPTY_LIST);
         }

    return result;
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you. I already thoughts about this solution. I just didn't want to put another code in the question. It's totally valid and another solution to the question.

We decided to fix the web service because it shouldn't give mixed classes results in one bucket. And then using a similar class like yours will be perfectly ok and gson will parse it automatically and easily.

I'll close the question as there isn't only one answer.

Comment: If you agree this is a possible answer. Will you accept it as an answer?

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo: instead of returning an instance of the dedicated class that separates objects, you should return a `List<Num>` as you did first. Because some clients may be interested by the whole list, not a list splitted in two, particularly if the order of items is important: they lose an information and have more processing to do on their side. Instead provide a class with a static method that will split the `List<Num>` and return the equivalent of the `Result` class described here. This way the clients have the choice.